# Это предложение является безличным?

Tags: орфография

Обычно лжецам прекрасно удается обмануть большую часть людей.

Answer (score 2):

**Удается** обмануть - глагол ***удаётся*** означает стихийную направленность действия на субъект, способность как бы невольного проявления  действия, подлежащего нет и быть не может - это **безличное** предложение.